# SQL statement to list all of the current database properties

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried a few different ways to list the db properties and have come up short.

```
SQL> SHOW DATABASE VERBOSE emp;
SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "DATABASE"
SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "VERBOSE"
SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "emp"
```

Heres another that I dont understand why its not working

```
 SQL> show database;
 SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "database"


SQL> DGMGRL
SP2-0042: unknown command "DGMGRL" - rest of line ignored.
```

Does anyone have ideas as to what I am missing.

Comment: "Properties" is really vague. What information are you specifically looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a table called `database_properties` - you should query that

```
select property_name, property_value, description from database_properties
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, you should be more specific

Answer (score 5):

If you wan the full version information for your DB then:

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$version;
```

If you want your DB parameters then:

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$parameter;
```

If you want more information about your DB instance then:

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$database;
```

If you want the database properties then:

```
SELECT *
  FROM database_properties;
```

If you want the "size" of your database then this will give you a close enough calculation:

```
SELECT SUM(bytes / (1024*1024)) "DB Size in MB" 
  FROM dba_data_files;
```

You will need DBA level permissions to see these views or you could request the data from your DBA and he will (probably) oblige.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW DATABASE` is not a valid SQL*Plus command.

The correct syntax is [SHOW option](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm#i2699447) where option is one of:

```
system_variable ALL BTI[TLE]ERR[ORS] [ { FUNCTION | PROCEDURE | PACKAGE | 
PACKAGE BODY | TRIGGER | VIEW | TYPE | TYPE BODY | DIMENSION | JAVA CLASS } 
[schema.]name] LNO PARAMETERS [parameter_name] PNO RECYC[LEBIN] [original_name] 
REL[EASE] REPF[OOTER] REPH[EADER] SGA SPOO[L] SPPARAMETERS [parameter_name 
SQLCODE TTI[TLE] USER XQUERY
```

Comment: Then I am confused. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28295/dbresource.htm I was here and the syntax to list the properties of a db is show database

Comment: Note the name of that manual:  Oracle Data Guard Broker
That is only used if you're managing a Data Guard implementation, and the command is only valid from within the Data Guard command line utility, DGMGRL.  It's *not* a valid SQL*Plus command.

Specifically, what information are you looking for?

Comment: I just want the properties of the current db

Comment: What properties and what do you mean by "properties"?

Comment: I would think in a db that yo9u have a list of properties, db owner, size, and so on